# On create select created row jQuery, jsf, pf

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jsf-2

So, on create i want to select that created row. My jquery on update works just fine but im not able to write proper code for create.

Comment: Please start by reading [ask]

Comment: Hi, please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   In this case, you would be expected to show what you have tried so far and which part you are having trouble with.